# How to set programatically a selector to a checkbox

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to set a selector to checkboxes that are created programatically, this way:

```
var cbAll = new CheckBox(Activity);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llAll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            cbAll.Text = "All zones";
            llAll.LeftMargin = 27;
            llAll.TopMargin = 24;
            cbAll.ButtonDrawable = //what to put here?
```

My selector (named cb_edit.xml) in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_active" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_default" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: i don't know what exactly you trying.but if u setting background ten try this  cbAll.SetBackgroundResource( Resource.Drawable.cb_edit); @Fustigador

Comment: I have png images for states selected, and unselected, and I need to change the default images of the checkbox for those custom images. In regular Android it is done, in the xml, doing android:button="@drawable/cb_edit". That's why I am using ButtonDrawable. In xamarin, it is donde using SetBackground?

Comment: you can do same in xamarin also add in xaml file

Comment: I need it to be created programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, add an XML into your drawable folder:

**CheckBoxDrawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/CheckedImage" />
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/UnCheckedImage" />
</selector>
```

- Then declare the checkbox and set the button drawable to it something like this:

  ```
  Checkbox btnOption = new Checkbox(context);
  btnOption.SetButtonDrawable(Resource.Drawable.CheckBoxDrawable);
  ```

That should make it work in case it does not revert

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what exactly you trying.but if u setting background then try this

```
cbAll.SetBackgroundResource( Resource.Drawable.cb_edit);
```